# How can I display HTML within an SVG document?

Tags: html, svg

I have SVG documents which I display directly in browsers (currently IE and Firefox) - by loading the *.svg directly into the browser. These documents contain text which I would like to display as "HTML", e.g. rendered in an HTML window/panel with word-wrap, subscripts and possibly scrolling. The SVG and HTML are well formed and managed under the correct namespaces.

A typical sort of element (without styles) might be:

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <rect x="100" y="200" width="300" height="400"/>
    <h:p xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
This is an <h:i>italic</h:i> and a <h:sub>subscript</h:sub> in a ...
very long ... paragraph which will need word wrapping and maybe scrolling
    </h:p>
  </g>
</svg>
```

It would be nice to be able to locate the text within a given bounding box (e.g. the <rect/>)

Note that at present I do not want to embed SVG within an HTML document and there is no need for recursion (e.g. no SVG within the HTML).

UPDATE:
Encouraged by @Sirko I found [this article](http://ajaxian.com/archives/foreignobject-hey-youve-got-html-in-my-svg) on the web it's 4 years old.

Comment: I think you'll have to take the HTML with inline SVG route if you want it to work in IE (and consistently across browsers).

Comment: @Erik you mean HTML contains SVG contains HTML? or HTML contains SVG contains refToParentHTML? Do if you have examples? Please add as answer if you do and I'll +1 it

Comment: The example code snippet in the question looks like it could be done with just HTML+CSS, or HTML with an svg background-image or some inline svg. Could you explain why you don't want to do it like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general the `<foreignObject>` shall be used for including different markups inside of SVG (see [MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Element/foreignObject) on this). In your case this other markup would be XHTML.

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <rect x="100" y="200" width="300" height="400" style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1px;"/>
    <foreignObject x="100" y="200" width="300" height="400">  
      <!-- XHTML content goes here -->  
      <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
        <p>
            This is an <i>italic</i> and a <sub>subscript</sub> in a ...
            very long ... paragraph which will need word wrapping and maybe scrolling
        </p>
      </body>  
    </foreignObject>  

  </g>
</svg>
```

This, however, has quite some compatibility problems between the major browsers!

Comment: What kind of compatibility problems?

Comment: @Alohci Actually the above code seems to render only in FireFox and Chrome for me. Opera and IE9 do not show any text, but no errors either ...

Comment: +1 @Sirko this is exactly the sort of thing I was wanting. It doesn't surprise me there are problems.I'll wait a bit to see if others have ideas and experience

Comment: @Sirko works for me in firefox but not in IE (just as you indicated). The Firefox appears to clip without scrolling - but that's probably manageable as I know the number of characters and their screen location

Answer (score 1):

Not only can you include HTML in SVG, but you can even include HTML in SVG in HTML in SVG in HTML ...

Here's some example code from [HTML in SVG in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458546/html-in-svg-in-html) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>HTML in SVG in HTML</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
    svg { border: 1px solid black; }
    svg div { border: 1px dotted blue; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="800" height="500">
  <foreignObject class="node" x="46" y="22" width="200" height="300">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <div>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. Pack my box with
         five dozen liquor jugs</div>
    </body>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Still, note that support for inline SVG in HTML documents remains "quirky" at best, even today (March 2014). For example, try this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/jslegers/full/nrFtG) in different browsers.