# How do I include a Font Awesome icon in my SVG image?

Tags: css, svg, font-awesome

I have an SVG that includes images:

```
<g><image id="myImage" class="myClass" x="12" y="15" width="10" height="10" xlink:href="/images/pic.png"/></g>
```

How do I replace that line w/ a font awesome icon:

```
<g><i class="icon icon-cloud-download" x="12" y="15" width="10" height="10"></i></g>
```

doesn't seem to work as the image doesn't show up.

Comment: You need to get the glyph elements from the svg.

Comment: I found this solution to work best: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243677/how-can-i-display-html-within-an-svg-document

Answer (score 131, accepted):

`i` is not valid SVG. You need to include the actual character that displays the icon. If you take a look at [font awesome's stylesheet](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-less/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome/variables.less) you will see...

```
.icon-group:before                { content: "\f0c0"; }
.icon-link:before                 { content: "\f0c1"; }
.icon-cloud:before                { content: "\f0c2"; }
.icon-beaker:before               { content: "\f0c3"; }
.icon-cut:before                  { content: "\f0c4"; }
.icon-copy:before                 { content: "\f0c5"; }
.icon-paper-clip:before           { content: "\f0c6"; }
.icon-save:before                 { content: "\f0c7"; }
.icon-sign-blank:before           { content: "\f0c8"; }
.icon-reorder:before              { content: "\f0c9"; }
.icon-list-ul:before              { content: "\f0ca"; }
.icon-list-ol:before              { content: "\f0cb"; }
.icon-strikethrough:before        { content: "\f0cc"; }
.icon-underline:before            { content: "\f0cd"; }
.icon-table:before                { content: "\f0ce"; }
```

But those are unicode characters encoded for CSS. In SVG you would need to change the syntax of example `\f040` to:

```
<g><text x="0" y="0">&#xf040;</text></g>
```

And then in your stylesheet add:

```
svg text {
   font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

According to Niek's comment, if you use the free version of Font Awesome 5+, you must use the following font-family declaration:

```
svg text {
   font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
}
```

Comment: @Duopixel This solution only works, if the svg is part of the website, where FontAwesome (css) is loaded, right? Is there a way, to include a single font into an "stand-alone" svg file? This file should be readable "offline" without loading the css files from webserver. Like a bundle: svg and FontAwesome definition into one svg file.

Comment: To have a standalone SVG with the embedded font you would need to embed the font as a data uri, if you need the details please open a new question.

Comment: @Duopixel I have added a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225954/use-fontawesome-icon-in-svg-without-external-files maybe you have an idea, how to solve it

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me. I have `<g class="info-container" transform="translate(240,283)"><text class="svg-icon" x="-60" y="0">&amp;#xf040</text></g>` and style `.svg-icon { font-family: FontAwesome; }` but it doesn't help. FontAwesome.css is attached to the page. And the icon shows as text. Why so?

Comment: @sedovav:here's what I had to do to make it work in d3.js. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12883617/127203. Basically the text should be "\uf040".

Comment: @Glenn u da real MVP!

Comment: Didn't you forget a semi-colon after the html escaped character string? So: `<g><text x="0" y="0">&#xf040;</text></g>`

Comment: @VincentSels yes, semi-colon should be added, not sure why this wasn't noticed before.

Comment: @Glenn - maybe you should edit the answer - \u works, &x definitely doesn't.

Comment: Note: in version 5, the font-family attribute should be `font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';` for free users.

Answer (score 27):

## [my Demo](http://jsbin.com/pekejanivi)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div title="Code: 0xe800" class="the-icons span3">

      <H3>Standard using:</H3>
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i>
    <br>
      <H3>SVG using:</H3>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 250)
  .attr("height", 250);

svg.append("text")
  .attr("x",0)
  .attr("y",70)
  .attr("font-family","FontAwesome")
  .attr('font-size', function(d) { return '70px';} )
  .text(function(d) { return '\uf083'; });
```

Comment: Thanks for the example with function(d) { return '\uf083'; }, took me a while to find this solution.

Comment: When I try to save this svg using window.btoa I am getting an error **Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.(…)**

Comment: Thanks, but I wonder what the difference between using HTML entity and D3js `text` function to add string to an HTML element?  like '\uf083' and &#xf083

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for all codes \uf185  \uf186 \uf763 \uf7ad

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me perfectly.

```
   svg.append('tspan')
        .attr('class', 'fa')
        .text('\uf05a')
```