# Why aren't fontawesome icons showing up in my svg?

Tags: html, css, svg, font-awesome

I'm having a strange problem of icons (from fontawesome) not showing up in my svg. They have always shown up on my local computer, so for a long time I didn't realize that something was wrong for other people.

For example, take a look at the first svg image on this post:
http://falconair.github.io/2015/01/05/financial-exchange.html

Where there are red and green "SELL" and BUY" words with prices and a bunch of boxes, there are actually supposed to be stick figures and other icons such as below:
[image]

One of the missing icons is this:
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/male/

In the css, I'm including fontawesome css. In svg, I'm using the relevant unicode character. In fact, the first image has a giant \uf183 because I was attempting to type out the unicode instead of pasting the character.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? I'm obviously not a web developer and I created the images to illustrate a point and now I'm having to spend more time fiddling with the image than the actual content.

Comment: Any chance you can post the HTML and CSS here? Hard to tell without it. Also, check the console to see if you have a 404 on the fontawesome.css. And lastly. It's \f183...not \uf183 ...as far as a I am concerned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SVG is an external file that is being imported as an `<img>`.  It has no idea there is a FontAwesome CSS file being linked to by your HTML file.

In the general sense, you would need to include the FontAwesome CSS file from your SVG as well.

**However** it is not quite as simple as that because you are including the SVG as an `<img>`.  Browsers have privacy constraints that disallow SVGs embedded as `<img>`s from referencing other external resources.  They **must** be self-contained.

The solution you will need to use is to include a `<style>` element in your SVG and embed the FontAwesome TTF font as a Data URI.

```
<svg width="500" height="200" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 500 200">  
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        src: url(data:font/opentype;base64,[...]) format('opentype');
      }
    </style>
    ...etc...
```

See: [use FontAwesome icon in svg without external files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225954/use-fontawesome-icon-in-svg-without-external-files)

Answer (score 1):

Link font awesome online to your project and try...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```