# Here Maps for JavaScript API : Markers with svg with font awesome

Tags: svg, maps, font-awesome, marker

Does anyone know if Here maps supports svg icons using font awesome? I've followed steps here [How do I include a font awesome icon in my svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984007/how-do-i-include-a-font-awesome-icon-in-my-svg) but it doesn't work. Regular svg works

```
'<svg width="33" height="33" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
'<circle stroke="__ACCENTCOLOR__" fill="__MAINCOLOR__" cx="16" cy="16" r="16" />' +
'<text x="16" y="20" font-size="10pt" font-family="arial" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" fill="__ACCENTCOLOR__" textContent="__TEXTCONTENT__">__TEXT__</text>' +
'</svg>',
```

but not with font awesome.

Comment: Have you included the font awesome font library?

Comment: @KheemaPandey Yea I've included it on the page

Comment: Include the svg for markers right?

Comment: Here is a way to do so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26039381