# Here Maps JavaScript API 3.0 Explorer How to set marker color

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I can't find any documentation or examples for setting a markers colour in version 3.0 API. you could do this with the 2.5, do any one know if marker colour is supported anymore

```
function addMarkersToMap(map) {
  var parisMarker = new H.map.Marker({ lat: 55.560789, lng: 12.981141 });
  map.addObject(parisMarker);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in the example in the [API Explorer](http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#maps-js/markers-on-the-map), creating an  `H.map.Marker` without specifying an `icon` results in a default image. If you need to have different colored icons, you will need to create them using [SVG Graphics](http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#maps-js/map-with-svg-graphic-markers).

```
function addSVGMarkers(map){
  var svgMarkup = '<svg style="left:-14px;top:-36px;"' +
      'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28px" height="36px" >' +
      '<path d="M 19 31 C 19 32.7 16.3 34 13 34 C 9.7 34 7 32.7 7 31 C 7 29.3 9.7 ' +
      '28 13 28 C 16.3 28 19 29.3 19 31 Z" fill="#000" fill-opacity=".2"></path>' +
      '<path d="M 13 0 C 9.5 0 6.3 1.3 3.8 3.8 C 1.4 7.8 0 9.4 0 12.8 C 0 16.3 1.4 ' +
      '19.5 3.8 21.9 L 13 31 L 22.2 21.9 C 24.6 19.5 25.9 16.3 25.9 12.8 C 25.9 9.4 24.6 ' +
      '6.1 22.1 3.8 C 19.7 1.3 16.5 0 13 0 Z" fill="#fff"></path>' +
      '<path d="M 13 2.2 C 6 2.2 2.3 7.2 2.1 12.8 C 2.1 16.1 3.1 18.4 5.2 20.5 L ' +
      '13 28.2 L 20.8 20.5 C 22.9 18.4 23.8 16.2 23.8 12.8 C 23.6 7.07 20 2.2 ' +
      '13 2.2 Z" fill="${COLOR}"></path>' +
      '<text transform="matrix( 1 0 0 1 13 18 )" x="0" y="0" fill-opacity="1" ' +
      'fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" ' +
      'font-weight="bold" font-size="13px" font-family="arial">${TEXT}</text></svg>'

  // Add the first marker
  var parisIcon = new H.map.Icon(
    svgMarkup.replace('${COLOR}', 'blue').replace('${TEXT}', 'P')),
    parisMarker = new H.map.Marker({lat: 55.5607, lng: 12.9811 },
      {icon: parisIcon});

  map.addObject(parisMarker);
}
```

To update the color, just create a new `H.map.Icon` replace the `icon` attribute of the marker.

Comment: An example with an icon suitably close to the standard marker... I found I needed to set an anchor to get the above SVG marker placed just right (creating the icon using new H.map.Icon(svgMarkupReplaced, { anchor: new H.math.Point(13,30) }); where the variable had the above SVG marker with COLOR and TEXT replaced). If you're going to use this a lot, you should be able to create a ColoredMarker subclass of Marker, which sets this from a constructor parameter, it wouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case if any one needed deafult marker icon in svg with text inside it.

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 263.335 263.335" style="enable-background:new 0 0 263.335 263.335;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M40.479,159.021c21.032,39.992,49.879,74.22,85.732,101.756c0.656,0.747,1.473,1.382,2.394,1.839   c0.838-0.396,1.57-0.962,2.178-1.647c80.218-61.433,95.861-125.824,96.44-128.34c2.366-9.017,3.57-18.055,3.57-26.864    C237.389,47.429,189.957,0,131.665,0C73.369,0,25.946,47.424,25.946,105.723c0,8.636,1.148,17.469,3.412,26.28" fill="${COLOR}"/>
    <text x="80" y="130" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="5em" fill="white">${TEXT}</text>
    </g>
</g></svg>
```

Comment: If it's any help, the URL encoded SVG source can be accessed from the icon: 
   `<icon>.f.a.data`