# How should one refresh the position of a largish number of marker positions in Here Maps 3.0?

Tags: here-api

**NOTE:** This is an old post, I've figured out most of the questions in the bullet points, read further for notes. I've written my remaining problem in the first edit.

Now that I discovered the new 3.0 Here Maps after the 2.n series, I don't know how to achieve the following:

- Clear the whole map
- Update marker positions using some marker ID
- Remove some specific markers using some ID

**<edit:** The last edit this far, I'll add it here as this got long. I rushed things, it looks like I don't know how to redraw markers on the map without causing marker flickering (that is, the map does not flicker, but the markers do upon removing and readding)! The `invalidateObject` is a method in ``H.map.clustering

**Question:** How should one update marker positions and then redraw the map?

See further for code as more context for this question. I took a quick way by removing the objects without holding a reference to previously added markers, updating their position and then redrawing the map. Alas, I couldn't figure out how to just update marker positions! There's about 50 markers which position I update every second or so. A point of note is that just removing all the objects and then re-adding them (with approximatelly the same looking standard markers) didn't cause flickering (both have `useCIT`, in 3.0 series I use also `HTTPS`) in the version 2.n of the API. The flickering happens on Windows 8.1 on IE, FF and Chrome and on Windows Phones with the 3.0 version.

```
 //Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020199/here-nokia-maps-javascript-api-3-0-explorer-how-to-set-maker-color.
 var markup = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28px" height="36px" >' +
            '<path d="M 19 31 C 19 32.7 16.3 34 13 34 C 9.7 34 7 32.7 7 31 C 7 29.3 9.7 ' +
            '28 13 28 C 16.3 28 19 29.3 19 31 Z" fill="#000" fill-opacity=".2"></path>' +
            '<path d="M 13 0 C 9.5 0 6.3 1.3 3.8 3.8 C 1.4 7.8 0 9.4 0 12.8 C 0 16.3 1.4 ' +
            '19.5 3.8 21.9 L 13 31 L 22.2 21.9 C 24.6 19.5 25.9 16.3 25.9 12.8 C 25.9 9.4 24.6 ' +
            '6.1 22.1 3.8 C 19.7 1.3 16.5 0 13 0 Z" fill="#fff"></path>' +
            '<path d="M 13 2.2 C 6 2.2 2.3 7.2 2.1 12.8 C 2.1 16.1 3.1 18.4 5.2 20.5 L ' +
            '13 28.2 L 20.8 20.5 C 22.9 18.4 23.8 16.2 23.8 12.8 C 23.6 7.07 20 2.2 ' +
            '13 2.2 Z" fill="${COLOR}"></path><text transform="matrix( 1 0 0 1 13 18 )" x="0" y="0" fill-opacity="1" ' +
            'fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" font-weight="bold" font-size="13px" font-family="arial" style="fill:black">${TEXT}</text></svg>'

    function createMarker(id, la, ln) {                                    
        var icon = new H.map.Icon(markup.replace('${COLOR}', '#FF8800').replace('${TEXT}', id));
        var marker = new H.map.Marker({ lat: la, lng: ln }, { icon: icon });

        return marker;
    }

var updates = updateBatch;
var len = updates.length;
var newMarkers = [len];
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var update = updates[i];
    var marker = createMarker(update.Id, update.Latitude, update.Longitude);
     newMarkers[i] = marker;
 }

 map.removeObjects(map.getObjects());
 map.addObjects(newMarkers);
```

For instance, in the *2.n* series for clearing the map there's `{map}.objects.clear`, but it looks like it's gone now and I can't locate the documentation for the 3.0 version of the API.

<edit: After a few hours of sleep I spotted the issue about removing on [Maps API for JavaScript Developer's Guide (3.0.5)](http://developer.here.com/documentation/versions) on page 26 and later, e.g. on page 76, there's `removeObjects()` to clear all.

Now I just need to figure out how to update marker positions that have been added to the map. A short snippet from the documentation:

> **Adding and Removing Objects**
>
> Each map object type corresponds to a class in the API. A newly created instance of such a class does not automatically appear on the map, but, like a node in the HTML document object model (DOM), must be added to the root. This means that to make an object appear on the map, it must be added to the map's root group through a call to the map object's method addObject(). Conversely, to remove an object from the map, a call to the map object's method removeObject() is required.
>
> Groups have their own addObject() and removeObject() methods and behave like container
>   elements in the HTML document object model. It is possible to add an empty group to the map and add individual objects later. The code below demonstrates how to create an empty group, add it to the map, then create a marker and make it a member of the group.

```
// Create a group that can hold map objects:
group = new H.map.Group();
// Add the group to the map object (created earlier):
map.addObject(group);
// Create a marker:
marker = new H.map.Marker(map.getCenter());
// Add the marker to the group (which causes
// it to be displayed on the map)
group.addObject(marker);
```

<edit 2: It looks like there's a method `invalidateObject (mapObject, changes)` in `H.map.provider`, which takes a `H.map` object. Then `changes` is a bitmask that defines the types of changes, but the documentation doesn't tell what should be put in if I'd like to redraw the map with markers in the new positions, there' just

> signed 32 bit integer (JS restriction) where bit operator can be applied to. The range is
>   [-2,147,483,648 ... 2,147,483,647] or [-2^31 ... 2^31 − 1]

**Question:** Should one use, say, -1 as the bitmask to redraw a map object?
(I'm off the development tools for a while now, so can't the hypothesis, though I'd like to know about these bitmasks in any case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of removing all the objects and then re-adding them, the trick is to add the markers to two `H.map.Group` objects to set up double buffering by using `setVisibility = true/false`, calling `.removeAll` to the one that has has been switched to background (by setting visibility to false) and switching the marker container variables.

A more elegant solution would be to have just one container, update the location of the markers there and then just remove the ones not having an update (or some other appropriate action).

```
function nonUpdated(markers, updates) {
    var map = {};
    var updatedMarkers = [];
    var nonUpdatedMarkers = [];

    for (var i = updates.length; i--;) {
            map[updates[i].Id] = null;
    }

    //The updated ones are here in case someone finds the code useful (remove in production).
    for (var key in markers) {
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                updatedMarkers.push(markers[key]);
        } else {
            nonUpdatedMarkers.push(markers[key]);
        }
    }

    return nonUpdatedMarkers;
}

//JS 6 brings Map, which is superior: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map.
var markers = Object.create(null);
var g = new H.map.Group();
map.addObject(g);

var updates = updateBatch;
var len = updates.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var update = updates[i];

    if (update.Id in markers) {
        markers[update.Id].setPosition({ lat: update.Latitude, lng: update.Longitude });
    } else {
        var marker = createMarker(update.Id, update.Latitude, update.Longitude);                        
        markers[update.Id] = marker;
        g.addObject(marker);
    }
}

var nonUpdatedToBeRemoved = nonUpdated(markers, updates);
if (nonUpdatedToBeRemoved.length > 0) {
    g.removeObjects(nonUpdatedToBeRemoved);
}
```

Comment: Reading this with great interest. I probably should ask a separate question but can you say whether these techniques work for animating markers? That is if I have a start position and end position and want to move between the two in 3 seconds I guess I'd have to interpolate the positions and then change them according to a timer.

Comment: I would say so, because these are the ones I find are the fastest, e.g. no flickering or sorts. [Double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering) was just me being lazy/busy and a workaround insteadofdoingthings properly. I suspect the map internally does double buffering. In any event, in the old APIs there's an example of this, see [here](https://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/public/api-for-js/demos/tracking-moving-map-object.html). It's from [here](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/api-explorer) from *Demos & Showcases* -> *Tracking a moving map object*.

Comment: To add, I believe the example can be ported rather straightforwardly to use the new API and it may demonstrate just the techniques and ideas you are looking for.

Comment: Many thanks for the links to the example! BTW they didn't work for me but I found it by going to http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/api-explorer and selecting Demos and Showcases.