# How do I include a bootstrap glyphicon in SVG

Tags: css, svg

I followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984007/how-do-i-include-a-font-awesome-icon-in-my-svg) to include glyphicons in my SVG but it's not working.

This is the SVG code that I want to implement the icon into:

```
  <text
    ng-attr-x="{{node.width/2}}"
    ng-attr-y="{{node.height/2+5}}"
    text-anchor="middle"
    ng-attr-fill="{{(node.activity.act_task==3 || node.activity.act_task==4)?'#FFFFFF':'#000000';}}">
    <tspan x="130" dy="0em">&#e003</tspan>
    <tspan x="130" dy="1.2em" ng-show="node.activity.act_type == 1 && node.height > 30"><a target="_blank" href="http://{{node.activity.act_info_url}}" style="text-decoration: underline">{{node.activity.act_info}}</a></tspan>
  </text>
```

and I added to my css file:

```
svg text{
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
}
```

But that didn't work, it just shows the `&#e003` as text instead of the search icon i am after which is the `glyphicon-search` icon.
I also tried `/e003` & `&e003` and `#e003` but without any luck.

Is there a way I can add in glyphicons into svg components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your entity is wrong.

Entities are by default decimal, not hexadecimal. If you want to use hexadecimal, you have to put an `x` after the `#`.

Also, the entity must end with a semicolon.  So what you should have used is:

```
&#xe003;
```