# How to fix font awesome icons not showing on mobile / chrome?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

```
<i class="fa fa-laptop-code large-icon"></i>
```

I use this html code for font awesome icon, it's showing perfectly on desktop , the problem is only with mobile view.**

Comment: Make sure that you are using the latest version of CDN. https://fontawesome.com/account/cdn

Comment: Check http or https this can also cause that kind of issues

Comment: You need use the SVG icons to mobile :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984007/how-do-i-include-a-font-awesome-icon-in-my-svg

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue when I tried to host font awesome icons by myself using the `all.css` file inside my CSS folder and importing it to the HTML page. I resolved the issue by importing the font awesome CDN link instead of using the `all.css` file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough, adding random query string to my fontawesome cdn link (example: ?v=7857324) worked for me. Looks like in my case I just needed to force reload the file for my users..

From

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css?v=7857324">
```

Comment: This worked for me. How in the hell did you determine that would work? Regardless, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible Problem 1**

You are using the

```
<i class="fa fa-laptop-code large-icon"></i>
```

if you are using the latest version of font-awesome it is most likely

```
<i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
```

try downgrading your version or updating your classes to "fas"

**Possible Problem 2**

Check on your mobile view if you have any css that is exists only on the mobile view e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width:600px){

}
```

Comment: so according to you, technically if i use 'fas' then the icons will be display on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

This problem mainly occurs when you use outdated Font Awesome CDN. Try using the latest one from their website.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

I was using the official fontawesome cdn. So I changed my current one for the one privide for fontawesome in their official web:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

Answer (score -8):

Make sure your mobile is connected to the internet