# Material Design Icon (MDI) inside SVG graphic?

Tags: svg, icons, vuetify.js, mdi

In my application I need to use the same icon in different places.

1. in v-card-action's button
2. in a SVG graphic

For the button it is as explained in vuetify documentation:

```
<v-card-actions>
    <v-btn value="previous" color="red" >
        <span class="hidden-sm-and-down">Previous</span>
        <v-icon right>mdi-arrow-left-circle</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
</v-card-actions>
```

But now, how to use the exact same icon (using it's name) in a custom SVG

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rec x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" stroke="grey" />
    <???> mdi-arrow-left-circle </???>
</svg>
```

- First, do i need to use SVG `<img>`, `<text>` or `<path>` primitive ?
- Second, how do i get the proper icon from it's name *mdi-arrow-left-circle* ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same question. This link came in handy when putting this together:

[How do I include a font awesome icon in my svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984007/how-do-i-include-a-font-awesome-icon-in-my-svg)

Disclaimer: I'm using TS components in Vue and have added Vuetify.

in the template I have a SVG:

```
<svg>
<text
    x="100"
    y="100"
    class="licon"
    fill="red">
    {{ content('mdi-close') }}
</text>
</svg>
```

The content method does this:

```
content(cls: string): string {
    // this copies the content from the pseudo element :before as it's needed to show the icon from material design
    const ele = document.querySelector('.' + cls);
    if(ele) {
        const styles = window.getComputedStyle(ele, ':before');
        return styles.content.replaceAll('"', "");
    }

    return '';
}
```

The last piece needed was to make sure to use the correct font (include in your stylesheet/etc):

```
.licon {
    font: bold 300px 'Material Design Icons';
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the solution of @trouble, thank you for that! The only thing I had to add to make it work was adding the icon somewhere on the site, even if it was invisible.

```
<i v-show="false" class="mdi mdi-close" />
```