# How to use an MDI icon inside SVG graphics?

Tags: vue.js, svg

This question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69020009/material-design-icon-mdi-inside-svg-graphic) but there are no satisfactory answers*. I am correctly displaying SVG text like this (in Vue.js)

```
  <text
      :font-size="imageSize()"
      :transform="transform(point)"
      :fill= "colour()"
      @click="emit('clickImage',props.img)"
      class="wheeltext"
      :x="point.x-15"
      :y="point.y+5">
        {{props.img}}
  </text>
```

but in some cases I want to display an MDI icon instead of text (probably using `v-if` to separate when the content of `props.img` is a character (string) or an MDI icon.
I'm happy to use either the name of the icon  (e.g. `mdiAccount') or its full string representation.

I'm also using Vuetify if that helps.

*Unsatisfactory because there are no upvotes and no accepted answer. I did try using an answer but it gave an error

> Property 'Symbol(debug.description)' was accessed via 'this'. Avoid
> using 'this' in templates

followed by many other consequential ones. I didn't understand that and couldn't find any help for it.

Comment: No answer has any upvotes, and none is marked as correct. Both by nwbies. I did try using them but ran into loads of errors.