# Element doesn't appear when appended in D3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm trying to create a legend that shows a color block, the name corresponding to that color, and a dropdown to change the color. Here is my code:

```
function create_legend(){
    var legend = legendSVG.selectAll("g.legend")
    .data(ext_color_domain)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend");

    var ls_w = 20, ls_h = 20;

    //create color blocks
    legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 20)
    .attr("y", function(d, i){ return height - (i*ls_h) - 2*ls_h;})
    .attr("width", ls_w)
    .attr("height", ls_h)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color_scale[i]; })
    .style("opacity", 0.8);

    //create text
    legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", function(d, i){ return height - (i*ls_h) - ls_h - 4;})
    .text(function(d, i){ return segment_map[i]; });

    //create dropdown for colors
    legend.append("div")
    .append("select")
    .attr("x", 80)
    .attr("y", function(d, i){ return height - (i*ls_h) - ls_h - 4;})
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(color_names)
    .enter().append("option")
    .attr("value", function (d) { return d; })
    .text(function (d) { return d; });      

}
```

The color & text appears, but the dropdown element does not.

[image]

Update: Ok, I tried doing the following but it gives me the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

```
'//create dropdown for colors
    legend.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("class", ".dropdown")
    .append("div")
    .append("select")
    .attr("x", 80)
    .attr("y", function(d, i){ return height - (i*ls_h) - ls_h - 4;})
    .selectAll("option")
    .data(color_names)
    .enter().append("option")
    .attr("value", function (d) { return d; })
    .text(function (d) { return d; });'
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458546/html-in-svg-in-html

Comment: OK I read it. Does that mean what I'm trying to do is impossible? or possible? It really wasn't clear from that link...

Comment: the . after append and before the ( is invalid

Comment: OK error gone, still nothing. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In SVG a html element can only be the child of a foreignObject element and a foreignObject element cannot be the child of a text element. A foreignObject element can be the sibling of a text element though so your DOM needs to look something like this.

```
g
|-   rect
|-   text
|-   foreignObject
        |- div
```

Answer (score 0):

For foreign object you should be appending the element like this:
`.append("xhtml:div")` instead of `.append("div")`

corrected full snippet.

```
 legend.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("class", ".dropdown")
    .append("xhtml:div")
    .append("xhtml:select")
    .attr("width", 80)

    .attr("x",function(d, i){ return width * i})
    .attr("y", function(d, i){ return height - (i*ls_h) - ls_h - 4;})
    .selectAll("option")
     .data(color_names)
    .enter().append("xhtml:option")
    .attr("value", function (d) { return d; })
    .text(function (d) { return d; }
```